# Python SDK - What's the difference between stellar-base and stellar-sdk?

Tags: python-sdk

There are two PyPI repositores for the Stellar Python SDK:

- [stellar-base](https://pypi.org/project/stellar-base/)
- [stellar-sdk](https://pypi.org/project/stellar-sdk/)

What's the difference between them?
When should each one be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stellar-base is an earlier version, it is no longer maintained, please use stellar-sdk.

You can find the development documentation here: https://stellar-sdk.readthedocs.org/